# How to use the ofxOpenCV addon from the OF project generator?

Tags: opencv, openframeworks

The problem is that I'm getting errors about 'DLL'

```
[ INFO:0@1.708] global D:\a\apothecary\apothecary\apothecary\build\opencv\modules\core\src\parallel\registry_parallel.impl.hpp (96) cv::parallel::ParallelBackendRegistry::ParallelBackendRegistry core(parallel): Enabled backends(3, sorted by priority): ONETBB(1000); TBB(990); OPENMP(980)
[ INFO:0@1.709] global D:\a\apothecary\apothecary\apothecary\build\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\anckg\Downloads\of_v0.12.0_vs_release\of_v0.12.0_vs_release\apps\myApps\paint\bin\opencv_core_parallel_onetbb460_64d.dll => FAILED
```

I've checked to make sure the `addon` was successful in the `addons.make` file and it worked.

I downloaded OpenCV but after reading the other discussions about the `OpenCV addon` the project generator should set up everything for you.